# Use Google Maps API MapView without permission

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

Does anyone know if it's possible to use the Google Maps API for Android's [MapView](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView) without giving it location permission? I just want to render a map and place a marker on it. I am not asking for the user's location in any way.

I cannot use the MapFragment because I am housing this view inside another Fragment, and nested fragments aren't supported until Android 4.2.

Comment: You do know that [SupportMapFragment](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment) along with all of the support library version of Fragments, support nested fragments back to API4?

Comment: What makes you think any of the Map APIs require the location permission?

Comment: support fragments go back to v4 but nested fragments don't. I don't think you can nest support fragments before v17.

Comment: You 100% can use nested fragments back to API 4.

Comment: It requires the location permission because it's crashing when I try to inflate the view with `Client must have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to request PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY locations.`

Comment: Feel free to include your code (XML you inflate, where you use the map if at all in code) to help with figuring out your issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the [specify Android permissions section](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/config#specify_android_permissions):

> The following location permissions are recommended, but you can omit them if your application doesn't access the user's current location, either programmatically or by enabling the My Location layer.

The only case where it should request the permission is if you are calling [setMyLocationEnabled(true)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#setMyLocationEnabled(boolean)).

Comment: OMG YES, thanks! I copied over the sample code which had `map.setMyLocationEnabled(true)`. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

If your just want to show a map with a marker, I'd suggest using the [Google Maps Static  Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/). Using this you can display an image of the map with markers and lot of other maps option. You can then open the actual Google Maps when the user clicks on the image. This would require the internet permission though.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting possibility. This would be a good fallback if there is no way to disable the permission on the native android maps API.